# How do I make my contact form responsive adding a few lines to my CSS file?

Tags: css

I have the following code in my contact form CSS file. How do I make the whole form responsive? I hope that this is possible considering that getting another form designed will be frustrating for me. Your help is much appreciated:

**CSS**

```
    #fcf-form {
    display:block;
}

.fcf-body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 85%;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left : 12.5em;
}

.fcf-form-group {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.fcf-input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}

.fcf-form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.fcf-form-control:focus {
    border: 1px solid #313131;
}

select.fcf-form-control[size], select.fcf-form-control[multiple] {
    height: auto;
}

textarea.fcf-form-control {
    font-family: -apple-system, Arial, sans-serif;
    height: auto;
}

label.fcf-label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.fcf-credit {
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #545b62;
}

.fcf-credit a {
    color: #545b62;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.fcf-credit a:hover {
    color: #0056b3;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.fcf-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .fcf-btn {
        transition: none;
    }
}

.fcf-btn:hover {
    color: #212529;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fcf-btn:focus, .fcf-btn.focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

.fcf-btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ee2348;
    border-color: #ee2348;
}

.fcf-btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ee2348;
    border-color: #ee2348;
}

.fcf-btn-primary:focus, .fcf-btn-primary.focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ee2348;
    border-color: #ee2348;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(38, 143, 255, 0.5);
}

.fcf-btn-lg, .fcf-btn-group-lg>.fcf-btn {
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}
.fcf-btn-block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.fcf-btn-block+.fcf-btn-block {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

input[type="submit"].fcf-btn-block, input[type="reset"].fcf-btn-block, input[type="button"].fcf-btn-block {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link href="contact-form.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="fcf-body">
<p></p>

<div id="fcf-form">
<h3 class="fcf-h3">Contact us</h3>

<form action="contact-form-process.php" class="fcf-form-class" id="fcf-form-id" method="post">
<div class="fcf-form-group"><label class="fcf-label" for="Name">Your name</label>

<div class="fcf-input-group"><input class="fcf-form-control" id="Name" name="Name" required="" type="text" /></div>
</div>

<div class="fcf-form-group"><label class="fcf-label" for="Email">Your email address</label>

<div class="fcf-input-group"><input class="fcf-form-control" id="Email" name="Email" required="" type="email" /></div>
</div>

<div class="fcf-form-group"><label class="fcf-label" for="Message">Your message</label>

<div class="fcf-input-group"><textarea class="fcf-form-control" id="Message" maxlength="3000" name="Message" required="" rows="6"></textarea></div>
</div>

<div class="fcf-form-group"><button class="fcf-btn fcf-btn-primary fcf-btn-lg fcf-btn-block" id="fcf-button" type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Please don't mind my putting the whole code here. As I am a newbie, I didn't know where that new line would go in the whole thing. Thanks for understanding.

PS: There is only this form on my page.

Comment: It would help to have the HTML of the form as well added in the question.

Comment: Asking "How do I make it responsive?" is pretty vague, there are lots of different "levels" of responsive-ness, and many ways to achieve each one. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Google Search Console is considering this page non-responsive and the form is the only thing that can be considered unresponsive. That's why I posted the CSS for the form only. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have added the form HTML as well. Thanks, John, for that.

Comment: Any updates on this one, guys?